# How do you program a button, that on press, will print out the entire ViewController in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, ios7

When a button is pressed, I would like the entire current UIViewController to print out. How can I program that?

I would like the entire UIView to print out on the default AirPrint Printer, or save as an image in the iDevice's photo library. I have tried to find an answer online, but have come up with nothing. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by print out? As in everything on the screen?

Comment: Print out as in on paper or an image in the photos library, sent by AirPrint.

Comment: This question is far too broad and a bit vague. Please narrow this down to a specific issue and describe what you have done or researched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to know if printing is available:

```
if ([UIPrintInteractionController isPrintingAvailable])
{
    [self printJob];

} else {

    // Printer not available
}
```

if it is available you can do something like this (using the `UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate` on your class header file):

```
-(void)printJob {

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [data writeToFile:@"foo.png" atomically:YES];

    UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    pic.delegate = self;
    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    pic.printInfo = printInfo;
    pic.showsPageRange = YES;
    pic.printingItem = data;

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
    ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed && error) {
            NSLog(@"Printing didn't complete. Error: %@", error);
        }
    };
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
    [pic presentFromBarButtonItem:barButton animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add it get it as an image use [`-drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawViewHierarchyInRect%3aafterScreenUpdates%3a)

When you tap on the button you have this method:

```
-(void)didTapPrintButton:(id)sender
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 0);
    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bound afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Do something with 'image'
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), NULL);
}
```

See the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum) for info on `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

The callback function for `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` should be declared in the same view controller:

```
-(void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
     // Image has been saved
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the above code in detail, and where I should put it?

Comment: Updated the answer to show the methods and callback method.